# Drop Mysql Event as soon as it completes the task

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-event

Good day. I was trying to find any documentation but i did not find any and neither an explanation to a situation where i actually need an event to be executed and after the event is execute within the given query statement the event must be dropped.

```
       $deleteEvent = mysqli_query($connection, "CREATE EVENT deletePareticipants
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO 
   BEGIN
      DELETE FROM mafia_room_participants WHERE room_id='$roomId';

      END");
```

This is the event and i put the `ON COMPLETION PRESERVE` as the [Mysql Documentation stated this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-event.html)

> Message: Event execution time is in the past and ON COMPLETION NOT
>            PRESERVE is set. The event was dropped immediately after
>            creation.

It says immediately after creation...does it mean that mysql event was dropped without actually running the specified query? I just need the query to happen and drop that event as soon as query happened.

Any ideas?

Comment: But you wrote `ON COMPLETION PRESERVE` instead of `ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE` in your query.

Comment: correct i was wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ON COMPLETION PRESERVE

remove this line